# Gitlab CI job missing artifacts from previous job

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a simple `.gitlab-ci.yaml` as below:

```yaml
.
.
.
stages:
  - create-ssh-key-pair
  - prerequisites
  - install-terraform
  - deploy
  - restart-sshd
  - test-ansible
  - ansible-playbooks
  - destroy


deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      # !/bin/bash
      KNOWNHOSTS=~/.ssh/known_hosts
      if [ -f "$KNOWNHOSTS" ]; then
        echo "$KNOWNHOSTS exists."  
        echo "" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts      
      else 
        mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts          
      fi
    - |
      #!/bin/bash
      ANSIBLEHOSTS=/etc/ansible/hosts
      if [ -f "$ANSIBLEHOSTS" ]; then
          echo "$ANSIBLEHOSTS exists."
      else 
          mkdir -p /etc/ansible/ && touch /etc/ansible/hosts
      fi
    - cat /etc/ansible/hosts
    - cat /etc/ansible/hosts
    - cp /etc/ansible/hosts ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - terraform init
    - terraform plan
    - terraform apply --auto-approve
    - pwd
    - ls
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./hosts
  tags:
    - gitlab-org
.
.
.
ansible-playbooks:
  stage: ansible-playbooks
  retry:
    max: 2
    when:
      - always
  script:
    - echo "ansible"
    - ls
    - pwd
    - cat hosts
    - ansible-playbook -i hosts ./ansible-playbooks/master_and_minions.yaml
    - ansible-playbook -i hosts ./ansible-playbooks/master.yaml
    - ansible-playbook -i hosts ./ansible-playbooks/join_master_and_hosts.yaml
  when: delayed
  start_in: 10 seconds
  needs:
    - job: test-ansible
  tags:
    - gitlab-org
```

I have here removed other jobs for easy-reading. So in `deploy` stage, the `gitlab-ci` says, the artifact is being uploaded as below:

```
Uploading artifacts...
./hosts: found 1 matching files and directories    
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok  id=656453560 responseStatus=201 Created token=mJXyVJbo
```

Ans in the `ansible-playbooks` job, where it says `cat hosts`, it gives this error:

```
cat: hosts: No such file or directory
```

This host file is in `/` of the build path, which is `/builds/iamdempa/k8s-gcp-cicd`

because in the `ls` command of `deploy` stage it the `hosts` file is there...

Can someone please help me?

**Problem: Is it not possible to send the artifact to other jobs as well? Can we only send the artifact to the consecutive jobs only?**

Answer (score 1):

[`needs:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) is used to run jobs **out of order**, only requiring the listed jobs to have completed. Here's a snippet from GitLab:

> The needs: keyword enables executing jobs out-of-order, allowing you to implement a directed acyclic graph in your .gitlab-ci.yml.
> This lets you run some jobs without waiting for other ones, disregarding stage ordering so you can have multiple stages running concurrently.

[`dependencies:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies) by default will pass on all artifacts from **previous jobs**.

However, for your `ansible-playbooks` job, only `test-ansible` is guaranteed to be a previous job. You should specify all jobs that your job requires to have run first under your `needs`, i.e.,

```yaml
ansible-playbooks:
  # ...
  needs:
    - job: test-ansible
    - job: deploy
```

Comment: Thank you. So in the `needs:` tag I should specify all the jobs in between the `deploy` stage and `test-ansible` ? What about the `restart-sshd` ? why you didn't put that?

Comment: And when you specify needs, does that mean according to above example of yours, both `test-ansible` and `deploy` has to be run for the `ansible-playbook` to run?

Comment: No. "You should specify all jobs that your job requires to have run first", as I said in my answer. The whole point of using `needs` is to enable running jobs in the fastest order possible. You only mention that you're missing artifacts from `deploy`, so that was the only one I added.

Comment: Yes, that is what needs means. If you are confused about what `needs` does, feel free to click on the link I provided in my answer to learn more.

Comment: I don't understand. So what does `need` really do? According to your example, does the `ansible-playbook` wait for both `test-ansible` and `deploy` stages to finish?

Comment: `needs` runs your job starting as soon as it possibly can, where the **only** delay it will have in starting is that it requires the jobs listed in `needs` to have completed first. No, `ansible-playbook` will not wait for those **stages** to finish - it will wait for those **jobs** to finish.